# Create local copy of webpage

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible for client side to store a local copy of the webpages after a server-side request, without manually saving the webpage (right click + save as...)?

I have multiple clients that displays a loop of webpages coming from the server. Each page have different media files such as images and swfs. As an alternative to the default cache mechanism, I would like for the client side, during the first load of webpages from the server, to store a copy of the webpages to the local of client side. That way I can reduce the requests coming from the clients every tiem the loop loads a web page request.

Whenever there are changes in the content, the server would tell the client side to request for the pages again and overwrite the local copy of the client side.

Comment: You mean from within the browser or in general? You can use `wget`.

Comment: In PHP http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @FelixKling within the browser? I have tried the AppCaching, however I 'm limited to using IE9 that's why I need to implement Google Chrome Frame to enable AppCaching using IE9 with GoogleChromeFrame.

Comment: What do you mean store? What is the purpose?

Comment: Don't vote to close this. Its a legitimate question, for which I have provided an answer. =)

Comment: @Geuis it would help if the question actually had details on what is the goal. Answering now is like playing the lottery.

Comment: It was pretty straightforward and clear to me.

Comment: @FelixKling the wget serves the purpose however, is there a browser way doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
localStorage['this_page'] = document.querySelector('html').innerHTML;
```

This will, of course, only work in modern browsers that support localStorage. There's no other browser API that will offer a way to store large amounts of data. Cookies are too small. You could use window.name as an alternative, but that's more a hack than anything else.

document.querySelector can, of course, be replaced with document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0], but just use querySelector since its supported everywhere localStorage is.